# Can context-free grammar generates $a^{2^n}$

Tags: context-free

Context-free grammar can generate the string $a^{2^n}$ for $n \geq 0$.

The production rule P is $S \rightarrow SS | a$.

The derivations is, for example:

1) $S \Rightarrow a$ (this is when n = 0)

2) $S \Rightarrow SS \Rightarrow aa$ (this is when n = 1)

3) $S \Rightarrow SS \Rightarrow SS SS \Rightarrow aaaa$ (this is when n = 2)

4) $S \Rightarrow SS \Rightarrow SS SS \Rightarrow SS SS SS SS \Rightarrow aaaa aaaa$ (this is when n = 3).

Am I right?

Comment: Yup :) Though it will eventually take an exponentially long amount of steps to achieve it for high enough $n$'s. (In fact it takes $a^{2^n}-1$ steps starting with $S$ to get to $a^{2^n}$)

Answer (score 3):

Your grammar actually generates the language $a^+$. For instance, since $S \to SS$, one gets $SS \to SSS$ and hence $S \to SS \to SSS \to aaa$.